# Performance monitoring of E-commerce Website

Tags: html, sql-server

What are the important parameters need to monitor while doing performance testing of e-commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

Page Load Time is he only thing worth worrying about:

https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/page-load-time-conversion-rates